# Switching to a new window in Selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am in a confused state. I am not able to get control of a window which is newly opened. I am using chrome browser for my testing.

Here is the scenario - I am in a facebook window and entered all my details and clicked on Log in. AFter the click event I am getting redirected  to a new window. My FB window is closed so I have lost all my control. But for some reason I am not getting control for the newly opened window. Please Help.

Comment: to get control of newly open window you should switch to that newly opend window using `driver.switchTo().window();`

Comment: Thanks Sachin. But this don't work. I think i have pass a string in this command. driver.switchTo().window("string"); But I dont have control over any window so I cant store any value in the string. I can be very wrong here. but this piece is giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

The below code takes you to the **last window** which is opened.

```
Set<String> allwindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String eachwindow:allwindow)

{

driver.switchTo().window(eachwindow);

}
```

If there are many windows and you want to move to the 2 window, then the below code works:

```
int i=1;
for(String eachwindow:allwindow)

{

driver.switchTo().window(eachwindow);
System.out.Println(eachwindow);
if(i==2)

{

break;

}

i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with:

```
Iterator<String> windowIterator = driver.getWindowHandles();
WebDriver popup = null;
while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
    String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
    popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = InitialiseAppium.driver.WindowHandles;
InitialiseAppium.driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[1]);
```

From there `windowHandles`  will get all the windows at the moment.
Then just use `SwitchTo()`